# Parallel For Loop - Problems when adding to a List

Tags: list, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I am having some issues involving Parallel for loops and adding to a List. The problem is, the same code may generate different output at different times. I have set up some test code below. In this code, I create a List of 10,000 int values. 1/10th of the values will be 0, 1/10th of the values will be 1, all the way up to 1/10th of the values being 9.

After setting up this List, I setup a Parallel for loop that iterates through the list. If the current number is 0, I add a value to a new List. After the Parallel for loop completes,  I output the size of the list. The size should always be 1,000. Most of the time, the correct answer is given. However, I have seen 3 possible incorrect outcomes occur:

1. The size of the list is less than 1,000
2. An [IndexOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(VS.71).aspx) occurs @ `doubleList.Add(0.0);`
3. An [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) occurs @ `doubleList.Add(0.0);`

The message for the ArgumentException given was: `Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.`

What could be causing the errors? Is this a .Net bug? Is there something I can do to prevent this from happening?

Please try the code for yourself. If you do not get an error, try it a few times. Please also note that you probably will not see any errors using a single-core machine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ParallelTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> intList = new List<int>();
            List<double> doubleList = new List<double>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
            {
                intList.Clear();
                doubleList.Clear();

                for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
                {
                    intList.Add(j % 10);
                }

                Parallel.For(0, intList.Count, j =>
                {
                    if (intList[j] == 0)
                    {
                        doubleList.Add(0.0);
                    }
                });

                if (doubleList.Count != 1000)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("On iteration " + i + ": List size = " + doubleList.Count);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's more likely a .NET bug or a bug in YOUR code?

Comment: Rule #1 of debugging: The bug is always in your code.  You can tell what's wrong just from the *title* of this...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I expect that System.Collections.Generic.List is not thread-safe, meaning that if you try to concurrently `Add` from two different threads, things will go wrong.  Ah yes, it says so in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

You could prevent this from happening in a number of ways:

- use a collection type that allows threadsafe adds (there are some [new ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) in .Net 4.0)
- lock before you add
- use thread-local storage for the collections, and merge them at the end
- ...

These are very typical issues you encounter with data parallel code.

Comment: +1. System.Collections.Generic.List is not thread safe. There are thread-safe collections in .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: +1 for your third suggestion which might be much faster than the other two.

Comment: @tster - yeah, there's even a Parallel.For overload to help with that strategy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783586.aspx

Comment: Brian is correct; the System.Collections.Generic.* classes are not thread-safe. See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/collections/LockingList.aspx for a thread-safe list class, or this one for a queue class: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38908/Thread-Safe-Generic-Queue-Class.aspx

Comment: All good suggestions, but I'd like to propose a fourth: Don't use `Parallel` at all.  There's so little work being done inside the `Parallel` block that the overhead of multiple threads and locking/merging is just going to end up costing more than the single-threaded version.

Comment: @Aaronaught, I'm pretty sure this is just an example from Kevin playing with the parallel stuff.  I doubt he has a real business need to add a value to a list for each element in an array he generated randomly which is 0.

Comment: tster: You're right that this is just a bad example for parallelization, but Aaronaught has a point that not every loop is a good candidate for it. If the synchronization or task scheduling overhead is more than the task itself, there's no point.