# Is it necessary to lock a C# list before adding elements to it if I do not intend to read from the list while elements are being added?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Here's an MWE:

```
Func<Int32, Boolean> MyFunc = (s) => {
    var res = false;
    // Insert function logic to modify the value to res
    return res;
};
var Result = new List<Int32> ();
var LockObj = new Object ();
ParallelEnumerable.Range (1, 100000)
    .ForAll (s => {
        if (MyFunc (s)) {
            lock (LockObj) { // IS THIS NECESSARY?
                Result.Add (s);
            } // End lock
        }
    });
```

This is what the situation boils down to.  Am I correct in thinking I don't need to lock Result if I am not going to ever query it before the ParallelEnumerable statement has finished executing?

**Please note**:  I know that the MWE is better solved by a "Where" clause, like so:

```
ParallelEnumerable.Range (1, 100000)
    .Where (s => MyFunc (s));
```

but for reasons not evident in the MWE, this cannot be done.

**EDIT**

Thank you to everyone who answered.  Thanks also for the comments.  I have corrected the error spotted by Tung.

Comment: I don't think I'm qualified to answer this question but I'm pretty sure that using a locking mechanism will negate the benefits of parallelism. Further, modifying a collection in a parallel fashion causes CPU cache problems, doesn't it?

Comment: Perhaps someone can correct me, but I don't think your lock is actually doing anything, mainly because you're locking on a local object

Comment: @Tung: no correction needed - you're right.  `LockObj` would need to be created outside of the parallel, at least (at the same scope as `Result`); typically these are created as class member fields since other methods may also modify the same resources.

Comment: @Tung - absolutely right, well spotted. The LockObj should be declared 1-on-1 with the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to `lock`. The Parallel.For will cause concurrent calls to `Add()`.

On a side note:

```
//var Result = new List<Int32> ();
var Result = new List<Int32> (100000);
ParallelEnumerable.Range (1, 100000)
```

Will make this a lot more efficient. Less growing also means less contention on the `lock`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to a generic list is not threadsafe. Locking is one possibility. You can also use one of the threadsafe collection types introduced im .Net 4.0

Have a look at [Parallel For Loop - Problems when adding to a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752358/parallel-for-loop-problems-when-adding-to-a-list) for more

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate a *lot* of contention by opting for one of the existing parallel collections:

```
ConcurrentBag<int> bag=new ConcurrentBag<int>();
ParallelEnumerable.Range(0,10000).ForAll(s => {if(MyFunc(s)) bag.Add(s);});
```

Comment: Wouldn't the (risk of) contention just move to _inside_ the collection?

Comment: Sure, but isn't ConcurrentBag (in particular) designed specifically to reduce contention when adding to the collection by distributing items over several internal collections?

Answer (score 0):

Use Semaphore.it will be manage accessing to shared resource(in your case common list).

Comment: But a full Semaphore is a lot more expensive than lock.

Comment: yeah you're right.i want to give him concept of using that.semaphore is easy to do.